# Join NaN values in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a list `y` which contains nan every after real number which prevents lines to get joined when plotted in matplotlib. I can try to plot this with `np.isfinite()` by masking `nan` data. However, can I ignore `nan` when they are more than 5 - so line join doesn't happen in the area with more than 5 `nan`s. `pandas` has built-in `series.fillna(limit=2)` which seems ideal, but I don't want to replace `nan`. I really need an example how this can be done.

The output I want is given below (with a gap between 7 and 14).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(20)
y = [np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 7, np.nan, 22, np.nan, 15, np.nan]

plt.plot(x,y, '-' )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a way to cleanly vectorize this.

If you really only have a handful of points, just write a loop to do it

```
def brute_force_clean_nans(x, y):
    x_clean, y_clean = [], []
    cnt = 0
    for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
        if np.isnan(_y):
            cnt += 1
            if cnt == 5:
                 # on the 5th nan, put it in the list to break line
                 x_clean.append(_x)
                 y_clean.append(_y)
            continue
        cnt = 0
        x_clean.append(_x)
        y_clean.append(_y)
    return x_clean, y_clean
```

You could also do things with `np.where`, looking at the runs etc, but if you have this few points it is probably not worth it.

Comment: I haven't tried your code yet, but I have over 160 series with more than 20, 000 data. Not sure if feasible to loop through every single datapoint. I will let you know later

Comment: I have corrected your code which contained an error in it. Other than this, thank you very much for solving my issue!